# React: res.json() data is undefined

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm having issues with getting data from my fetch API. It was working previously when I had "test" inside of a class. Now that it's inside of a function, I get "undefined" when I try to console.log(data). (Note, the API call is working on the server. console.log(res.json()) returns a data. I'm LOST.

```
const test = () => {
    fetch('/api/test/', {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },

      //make sure to serialize your JSON body
      body: JSON.stringify({zip: val})
    })
    .then(res => { res.json()}) //THIS RETURNS OK
    .then(data => {console.log({data})}) //THIS IS WHERE I HAVE PROBLEMS
  }
```

EDIT:

I also tried

```
.then(data=> {console.log(data)})
```

and

```
.then(data => {console.log([data])})
```

is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

[Arrow_functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

You should return res.json() to work successfully;

```
    .then(res => { return res.json()})
```

or

```
    .then(res => res.json())
```

Comment: Hello Ahmed! I am currently using .then(res => {return res.json()})

I'm new to Stack overflow and made a mistake putting my code in haha. I updated the post to reflect what I'm experiencing. Thanks!

Comment: hello dear, you still use ".then(res => { res.json()})".

please update your code and test it again. it will work successfully.

use this function i'm sure it will work https://pastebin.com/j7DVZjW3

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Perhaps there is a misunderstanding. i am using currently

    .then(res => { res.json()}) 
    .then(data => {console.log({data})})

are you saying that I need to use  .then(res => { res.json()}) twice?  .then(data....) is where I'm having issues. .then(res...) works fine

Comment: @shadow_code to get `data` you need to return `res.json()` in previous step.
`.then(res => { res.json()})` (with {}) does not return `res.json()`, `.then(res => res.json())` (without {}) does.

Comment: Promise like pipeline. first .then() return value to next .then() so if first .then() not return any value. the next .then() data will be undefined.

to work successfully. you should return res.json() in first .then();

Comment: Sorry about that! I have another file (server.js) that has the return res.json(data). I'm using express on the backend.

Comment: so use .then(res => { return res.json()}) instead of .then(res => { res.json()})

Comment: I'll give that a try Ahmed. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome dear. you should read about Promises and arrow function in js